# Javascript function running multiple times in Firefox only once in Chrome, why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I've got a file upload field which i added a jQuery change to.

In chrome it works great, the loadImage function replaces a placeholder pic with a render of the pic to be uploaded.  In firefox the following code renders 3 times (there are 3 "1"'s in the console, but only one "2" from the onchange handler) and the image is subsequently removed after it is added.

**Why does this happen in Firefox, and how can i prevent it?**

Coffeescript (i can convert if anyone likes to read js better):

```
$('#project_display_pic').change (e) ->
  console.log "2"
  value = $(this).val()
  value = value.replace("C:\\fakepath\\","")
  $('#display_pic_uploader > p').text(value)
  loadImage(
    e.target.files[0],
    ( (img) -> 
      console.log "1"
      $('#display_pic_preview > img').remove()
      $('#display_pic_preview').append(img)
    ),
    {maxWidth: 212}
  )
```

Haml if that helps (#project_display_pic is the id of the filefield):

```
    #display_pic_preview
      = image_tag( @project.display_pic.medium.url, :class => "default_pic" )
    #display_pic_uploader
      %p Add display image
      = f.file_field :display_pic
```

Comment: I'm using [this plugin](https://github.com/blueimp/JavaScript-Load-Image) to show an image preview of the selected image.  The loadImage() function accepts a File or Blob object or a simple image URL (e.g. "http://example.org/image.png") as first argument. If a File or Blob is passed as parameter, it returns a HTML img element if the browser supports the URL API or a FileReader object if supported, or false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at [the plugin's code](https://github.com/blueimp/JavaScript-Load-Image/blob/master/load-image.js), it appears that it invokes your render-callback for the image object's `onload` and `onerror` events. Perhaps Firefox erronously counts the scaling of the image as a load event or something? Or perhaps the error event is being triggered for no good reason.

Eitherway, a quick fix could be something like this:

```
# Builds a function to show the loaded image
# The function stores the last img object it received,
# and doesn't try to show the same one twice in a row
createRenderCallback = ->
  lastImg = null

  (img) ->
    return if img is lastImg # don't handle the same img twice
    # Note that if the image failed to load, `img` will be undefined
    # You may want to check for that before trying to append it
    $('#display_pic_preview > img').remove()
    $('#display_pic_preview').append(img)
    lastImg = img # remember the img

# Attach the file input's change handler (pretty much the same as before)
$('#project_display_pic').change (e) ->
  value = $(this).val().replace("C:\\fakepath\\","")
  $('#display_pic_uploader > p').text(value)
  loadImage e.target.files[0], createRenderCallback(), { maxWidth: 212 }
```

You could do something similar in the plugin's code, to avoid it re-calling the callback. Or you could log some stuff from the plugin to see precisely what's going on.

---

**Edit:** Since inserting the image into the DOM appears to trigger the render callback, you can try this:

```
createRenderCallback = ->
  lastImg = null

  (img) ->
    return if img is lastImg
    lastImg = img # <-- Move this line to here, i.e. before inserting the image
    $('#display_pic_preview > img').remove()
    $('#display_pic_preview').append(img)
```

**Or**, you can simply remove the event listeners instead of keeping a record of the `lastImg`

```
renderCallback = ->
  if img? # this function was called from an onload event
    img.onload = img.onerror = null

  else  # called from an onerror event
    @onload = @onerror = null

  $('#display_pic_preview > img').remove()
  $('#display_pic_preview').append(img) if img?

$('#project_display_pic').change (e) ->
  value = $(this).val().replace("C:\\fakepath\\","")
  $('#display_pic_uploader > p').text(value)
  loadImage e.target.files[0], renderCallback, { maxWidth: 212 }
```

Comment: wow, thank you, stack overflow is incredible, the amount of time you put into this is more than i could have asked for.

Comment: I tried the custom callback, still same story, i think you are right about the error, on error it triggers the callback, interestingly enough when i comment out these two lines     $('#display_pic_preview > img').remove()
    $('#display_pic_preview').append(img) i don't get the callback x 3, ill delve in deeper.

Comment: @AlexMarchant Interesting - I actually thought that that might be the case (that inserting the image would trigger the callback), but dismissed since it seemed ridiculous. There are 2 things you can try - I've updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

firefox calls this function multiple times with an error. this code should also work (check if it is an image object by checking the width property:

```
loadImage(file, function(image) {
        if(typeof(image.width) !== "number") { // make sure its an image and not an error
          return;
        }
}
```